# How to change Maya UI text font color?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, maya, maya-api

I want to change the font color of a text in an UI, but it's seems that there is nothing in [the text command doc](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/text.html) to do this. It's possible to change the background color, but nothing about the font itself.

I searched around the internet and found this code to change a button text color using PyQt ([source](http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?p=7751492#post7751492)).

```
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omUI
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sip
bt = sip.wrapinstance(long(omUI.MQtUtil.findControl(_the_button_name_)), QtGui.QPushButton)
bt.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: yellow}')
```

So, I have two questions:

First, what should I use, instead of `QPushButton`, to edit the color of a  text control, and two, the button color here is changed to `'yellow'` and I'd like to change it to a custom color value, is there a way to also do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using the setStyleSheet function you are changing the properties of the style with a syntax similar to CSS, so if we want to use a specific color we can pass the values as rgb or hex code as shown below:

```
pb.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: rgb(1, 1, 240)}')
pb.setStyleSheet('QPushButton {color: #0101F0}')
```

You can also apply to any widget without telling you to set the widget as shown below:

```
some_widget.setStyleSheet('color: #0101F0')
```

For text use the following:

```
lb = sip.wrapinstance(long(omUI.MQtUtil.findControl(_the_label_n‌​ame_)), QtGui.QLabel)
lb.setStyleSheet('color: #0101F0')
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer the second part of my question :) Do you know how to apply this to a text control instead of a button control?

Comment: @UKDP You've updated my answer, but I'm a bit confused: what do you call text control, to a QLabel; QLineEdit, QTextEdit?

Comment: That's the thing... I don't know which widget Maya use to display text in UIs, and I don't even know if there is a way to get that information other than by testing...

Comment: Run the following please: `lb = sip.wrapinstance(long(omUI.MQtUtil.findControl(_the_button_name_)), QtGui.QLabel)
print(lb)`, Change `_the_button_name_` appropriately to the text id, and tell me what you get please.

Comment: Perfect! It's a `QLabel` in the end. Thank you! Here is the output: `<PyQt4.QtGui.QLabel object at 0x7f38c2d8c8a0>`

Comment: Of course, could you please edit it with the correct widget? For the other people who would look for the same thing. Thanks again